# Print Function in Linked List c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

this is what I'm coding:

```
template<typename T>
inline void LinkList<T>::print() const
{
    for (Iterator<int> iter = begin(); iter != end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

and it's saying that this line:

```
(Iterator<int> iter = begin(); iter != end(); ++iter)
```

has this error:

```
`const Iterator<T> LinkList<T>::begin(void)' cannot convert `this` pointer from `const LinkList<int>` to `LinlList<int>&`
```

By the way:

```
template<typename T>
inline const Iterator<T> LinkList<T>::begin()
{
    return m_first;
}

template<typename T>
inline const Iterator<T> LinkList<T>::end()
{
    return m_last;
}
```

this is so that I can print out what I have in my list. This is for class so I HAVE to have it like this.

Edit:
so I did everything y'all suggested to do but it gave me errors so i went back to my original code, now i have different errors : /

this is for begin(); and end();

`return`:cannot convert from `Node<T>` to `Iterator<T>`

I don't exactly know what other information y'all need to help y'all out.the values for m_last and m_first is a Node

everyone in my class seems to have the same issue however apparently the code does have a right answer because the teacher has a working code.

I solved the question!!!

```
template<typename T>
inline const Iterator<T> LinkList<T>::begin()
{
    Node<T> *m_first;
    return m_first;
}

template<typename T>
inline const Iterator<T> LinkList<T>::end()
{
    Node<T>* m_last;
    return m_last;
}
```

granted i don't know if it works the way it is intended yet!

Comment: *granted i don't know if it works the way it is intended yet!* is a lovely thing to read. Too many questions here are founded on the mistaken belief that compiles == logically correct, and on inspection something was done, a cast usually, to remove the error message telling the asker that what they wrote was wrong (and sometimes why).

Answer (score 0):

Your `begin()` and `end()` functions are not `const` therefore they cannot be invoked on `const` instances of `LinkList<T>`. If you change your `begin` and `end` functions as follows:

```
template<typename T>
inline const Iterator<T> LinkList<T>::begin() const
{
    return m_first;
}

template<typename T>
inline const Iterator<T> LinkList<T>::end() const
{
    return m_last;
}
```

You should be fine.

Alternatively, you can make your print function non-const but I do not recommend that. Print functions should not modify the object and so `const` on the print function makes sense.

Comment: I did this and it gave more more errors on the same lines AND on the begin and end lines : /

Comment: this will allow to get a non-const `Iterator` to a `const LinkList`, which isnt good. One needs `const_iterator`s to get it right

Comment: @CCC This is almost the right thing to do, but we need more information in the question to be able to tell you exactly what the right thing to do is.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Good point, but that really depends on what `Iterator` is. Without the typedef we can't really say.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think thats the reason why

Comment: exactly, the question is too unclear. Though I cannot imagine any `Iterator` that would make your `begin()` and `end()` do the right thing and be constcorrect

Comment: And we shouldn't ignore the fact that the assignment may be flawed and this (or similar hackery) is the ONLY thing you can do, but that determination needs a more complete question.